# How can the bot take in two or more arguments as a command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
module.exports = {
    config: {
        name: "help me",
        noalias: ""
    },
    run: async (bot, message, args) => {

    }
}
```

I have this piece of code however when I run the command it does not do anything (There's code inside the `run: async...` I removed it to keep it short.) When I do `!!help me`, `!!help`, or `!!me` it does not do anything. The code below this message will be my `message.js` file.\

```
const { PREFIX } = require('../../config.json');

module.exports = async (bot, message) => {

    let args = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    let cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;

    var commandfile = bot.commands.get(cmd) || bot.commands.get(bot.aliases.get(cmd))
    if (commandfile) commandfile.run(bot, message, args);
}
```

Discord.JS Version: `12.2.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're removing the first argument when you do `args.shift()`. Don't do that. It's taking in the command name as just "help", and "me" as `args[0]`, which isn't bad, but doesn't work with what you're trying to do.

Instead, make it take in the argument at index position 0 and use that as the command name:

```
let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(/ +/g);
let cmd = args[0];
```

You shouldn't have multiple words as a command name. Make it `helpme`, `help` or perhaps `help-me`, otherwise properly handling user input will be made unnecessarily difficult. This is why it didn't do anything, since the command name was `help me` but it interpreted the command as just `help`.

Comment: The issue wasn't the fact that he removed the first argument, it was his regex, which like you said evaluated to "help" and not "help me"

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code makes me think you'd be better off matching the commands using regex like github/telebot does. Here is a short example how this could look like:

```js
const watchRegExp = /^\/watch ([a-z0-9]{64}) ([0-9]*) ?(.*)$/;

// let's say you sent: /watch 81a40da1f3e110017a6982e9e354577926ac047f57a954f70f365e8f5ae65ac6 5 cocacola

bot.on(watchRegExp, (msg, props) => {
  const txid = props.match[1]; // '81a40da1f3e110017a6982e9e354577926ac047f57a954f70f365e8f5ae65ac6'
  const threshold = props.match[2]; // 5
  const label = props.match[3]; // 'cocacola'

// do your stuff here

}
```

Hope this helps a bit,
Cheers